# Javadoc on CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript and seems that I can't find any document generator for CoffeeScript using Javadoc syntax. The only one I could find is available as a patch to the CoffeeScript compiler.

So, what do you use to generate documentation from Javadoc comment on CoffeeScript or how do you document your function arguments and return values?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, JavaDoc syntax has never really caught on with JavaScript developers. There are those who use something like it—notably Google—but it's kind of at odds with JS, which doesn't have static typing and allows any number of arguments to any function.

If you want to create beautiful documentation with CoffeeScript, the standard is [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/) (its home page is an excellent example). If you want to create JavaDoc-style comments for every function... well, you'll have to create them by hand, and escape them with backticks.

Alternatively, you could work in CoffeeScript until your code is release-ready, then document the resulting JavaScript.

Comment: There's also JSDoc, if you want something more JavaDoc-like. But Docco is amazing.

Comment: Be aware that docco does not support multi-line comments, recursive source directories, specifying output directory. Pfff!

Comment: @alexandru.topliceanu As I understand it, docco is sort of a proof of concept and itch-scratch that grew more popular than expected. You could always contribute a patch or two to add those features. (If I can ever find the time, I'll probably contribute a proper command-line option parser so things like `--help` work)

Comment: Docco doesn't solve the same problem. There's a big difference between annoted (sometimes called "literate") code, and API documentation.

Answer (score 15):

Docco is great for prozedural coding style. If you want to document an API, [coffeedoc](https://github.com/omarkhan/coffeedoc) is for you.

Comment: docco and coffeedoc are complementary which is really nice :) thx for pointing it out ^^

Answer (score 7):

People looking forward to using javadoc style documentation in coffeescript can checkout codo ( http://netzpirat.github.com/codo/ ) which provides support for a subset of javadoc and automatically infers class names, function names and parameters from source code.

Comment: YES. This is the most natural-looking solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/). I can add comments using a syntax similar to Javadoc to my classes, methods and events. The documentation gets output as html/css files and you can even customize the page layout.

Check this documentation example: http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/api/

PS: It relies on Node.JS and you need to install the package yuidocjs

```
npm install yuidocjs -g
```